# QT: Signal / Slot connection via connect or on_

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to QT. As far as I can see, there are two ways to connect signals and slots with each other. One way would be using the `connect` method. When e.g. wanting to put a method `ButtonReleased()` to the slot that is triggered after the `released()` signal of a pushButton with name `pushButton`, one could write:

```
 connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(ButtonPressed()));
```

However, as far as I see, one could also define a method with name `on_pushButton_released()` to achieve the same connection. Is there any difference between both methods and if so, which one is preferred?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed two main ways to connect signals to slots.

The first one, using the `connect` method allows to connect *any* signal to *any* slot (or signal) as long as the function signatures match. This is the main way to connect signals in Qt.

The second way are member methods that are called `on_ObjectName_SignalName()`. These are automatically connected by Qt, if a UI element called `ObjectName` exists and has a signal called `SignalName`. This is specifically meant for the use case of having some Widget with a separate `.ui` file, which contains these elements that you want to connect to. As such, this mechanism does not work if you create UI elements "by hand" in your C++ code.

As you can see, the second mechanism has very specific requirements that need to be satisfied to work, although these are not uncommon. So if you have satisfied these conditions I see no Problem in doing it this way, but others may disagree and this is largely personal preference.

Also note: The syntax in your question is the *old* syntax from Qt4. If you are using Qt5 and newer, it is highly advised to use the [new syntax.](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

You can read more about signals and slots on the [Qt Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).

Comment: "automatically connected by Qt" means that ui compiler adds `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName()` to generated code in `setupUi()`. If your `QObject`-derived class doesn't go through ui compiler (is not widget or has no `*.ui` file), you need to call it yourself.